# What is the difference between a single backslash followed by a space ("\ ") and two backslashes with a space in between ("\ \") in a path directory?

Tags: bash, macos, backslash

I am currenty using Bash on MacOS Mojave and the path directory to the Google Chrome application is: "/Applications/Google\ \Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ \Chrome." I'm curious to find out what the difference between a backslash-space and a backslash-space-backslash is. When I echo it out, there doesn't seem to be a difference in the outputs.

Comment: The \ signifies that your directory name has a space so if your folder is *Google Chrome*, then in bash you would signify it as Google\ Chrome

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was wondering about the difference between that and a double backslash with a space in-between.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in whatever you're using to display the path. Where are you seeing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single backslash character right before an alphanumeric character (`A-Za-z`) does nothing.

This is pointless but also valid

```
/Applications/Google\ \Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ \C\h\r\o\me
```

The single backslash before the **space** character escapes the character that means the space is treated as a literal space rather than the bash parameter separator.

The standard syntax is backslash space ("\ ")

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

However if the whole path is wrapped in single or double quotes the backslashes are not needed

```
'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
```

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind answering, I have a follow up question. if a backslash followed by a single character does nothing, what is it's purposein bash?

Comment: *A backslash followed by a single **alphanumeric** character does nothing*. It's used to escape special characters.